# Using the array method from the numpy package

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to use the array method from the numpy package, but I get an attribute error and it says that there is no method called array. what is the problem?

```
import numpy as np

x = [2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9]
y = np.array(x)
print(y)
```

AttributeError: partially initialized module 'numpy' has no attribute 'array' (most likely due to a circular import)

Comment: it is not importing numpy correctly probably because you have a file named numpy.py

Comment: Yes, you mentioned the right point. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to debug this behaviour is to print the origin of the file that you are importing:

```
import numpy as np
print(np.__file__)
```

This will return the path of your imported package and you could realise that it is not the one you intended to import.